# How do I add third party puppet modules without committing them to source control?

Tags: puppetmaster, dependencies

tl;dr: **How do I manage modules for a Puppet Master, like I do using `requirements.txt` for Python or using Bower for JavaScript?**

Here's an example.

Say I want to install the puppetlabs/firewall module, but I don't want to commit its source to source control.

https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/firewall advises the following:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-firewall --version 1.8.1
```

However, this seems... off to me, somehow. I'm not saying code-smell, but maybe my code-nose twitched a little, you know what I'm saying?

Especially since I was really hoping to use the `puppetmaster` module to get rid of our ticky-tacky little fabric+jenkins+bash+cron mess that currently manages our Puppet Masters.

I'd hoped to find something like a puppetmodule provider for package resources that would allow me to automate Puppet Module installation on our Puppet Master.

Is it as simple as adding all the modules I need as dependencies in the `puppetmaster` module's modulefile? https://github.com/fsalum/puppet-puppetmaster/blob/master/Modulefile

That feels hacky.

Anyway, I'm used to stuff like `requirements.txt` in Python and Bower in JavaScript.

BTW, I tried searching the forums for this, but I ended up with answers like the following:

[Best way to manage third-party / custom-built software with Puppet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/477698/best-way-to-manage-third-party-custom-built-software-with-puppet)

[How to install packages from source code with Puppet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/488508/how-to-install-packages-from-source-code-with-puppet)

**What does Puppet Master have like `requirements.txt` or Bower that I can use for Puppet modules?**

Comment: // , This is strictly a question about Puppet dependency management as applied to a Puppet Master using Puppet Open Source.

Comment: // , Because I'm asking about dependency management, I think it might belong in StackOverflow in stead, but I've noticed higher quality Puppet answers on serverfault.com than elsewhere, even on the https://ask.puppet.com forum.

Comment: Have a look at [r10k](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k).

Comment: What is all the `// ,` about?

Comment: // , Having a sense of humor, perhaps?

Comment: // , @gf_, I investigated, and it looks like r10k will work. I think it's a proper answer to this question. However, it looks like CEntOS 6 with Puppet <= 3.6 does not play too nicely with r10k's dependencies.